# Actionsheet instead of segue when clicking on uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uiactionsheet

Here's my ultimate goal in all of this.  I have a viewcontroller with a table added to the view.  I've set the cells to static, and I'm going to place the selected options in the cell.  I want an actionsheet with a picker view on it.  I have several arrays on the view which contain the various options.  When someone clicks the cell I want it to call a method which checks which cell was click, passes the picker view the correct array of options to display and shows the action sheet.

I've manually added a table to the view using the storyboard, but when I ctrl drag from a cell it only gives me the option to add a segue.  How do I set it so the cell click just goes to a method I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I guess that should have been pretty obvious.  I only needed to add the action from the storyboard if it was a segue I think.

Answer (score 1):

`- tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath`  and `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should work. Did you try them? Your viewController needs to adopt `UITableViewDelegate`.